# Merge and rebase remote branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have one local branch `master`, and track two remote branches `master` and `dev-me`. Meanwhile, another developer has his own local `master`, and tracks the same remote `master` and his own dedicate remote branch `dev-other`.

From time to time, we each respectively push from own local `master` to remote dev branch (i.e. `dev-me` or `dev-other`). We then want to merge our remote `dev-x` branches into the remote `master` branch.

I am thinking to do the following:

1. Either of us *merges* his remote `dev-x` branch into remote `master` branch.
2. The other person *rebases* from this merged remote `master` branch to his own remote `dev-x` branch.
3. The same person from step 2) *merges* back to the remote `master` branch.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Just to clarify to me. In the step 2 you would rebase by putting the dev-x commits on top of the merged master, right ? If so I don't see a problem.  Dev1 could also merger his/her branch to remote master and then Dev2 merge his/her branch to the result of Dev1 merge

Comment: @AndréOriani, yes, that's indeed the case, the rebase step takes in the merged changes from the remote `master` and applies on top the changes from the remote `dev-x` branch.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using branching properly. Take a look at my post and see that you should not focus on what dev has what master and main branches. You should be focusing on work in progress branches or feature branches and using other branches to manage their integration:

http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Answer (score -1):

You are overcomplicating it. Think of everything in git as a local operation and ignore other people and consider the remote repo to be a shared storage area.

It sounds like (if i have you right) you each work in master but push both to origin/master and origin/dev-something. This works, but it can be confusing. If you work in master, push to master. If you want to push to dev-something, **work in a local copy of dev-something**.

As it sounds like you have it, if you want to merge all the remote stuff, do this:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git merge origin/master origin/dev-me origin/dev-other
[resolve conflicts]
git push origin master:master
```

If you decide to use rebase, you'll need to rebase each remote branch onto master sequentially which, while giving you a linear history, doesn't really represent the reality of parallel development. Plus you need to decide whose changes come "first".

I would suggest that it is better if each of you work in a local dev-whatever branch and push to the upstream version of that branch exclusively. When you want to get code into master, checkout a local copy of master, merge your local copy of dev-whatever, and push your local master back up. Thusly:

```
git checkout dev-whatever
git fetch --all
git merge origin/dev-whatever
[hack hack hack]
git commit -a
git push origin dev-whatever:dev-whatever
[decide you want to integrate what you've got into master]
git checkout master
git merge dev-whatever
git push origin master:master
```

If both of you do this, then you will each be integrating your own changes in. If your co-worker has already pushed, your push with his/her own merged in changes, your push will fail. Not to worry, all you need to do at that point is:

```
 git fetch --all
 git merge origin/master
 [resolve conflicts]
 git push origin master:master
```

You can replace merge with rebase in this case and just use the "he got their first" method of deciding commit order.